# window.pageYOffset is deprecated what is the replacement

Tags: javascript

window.pageYOffset   is deprecated what is the replacement

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }`your text`
```

I am trying to make it functional

Comment: `pageYOffset` is not deprecated - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset). Why do you believe it is?

Comment: It is a synonym for [scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) so if you want to use the standard of today's browsers, use that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

In web development, both the `scrollY` and `pageYOffset` properties are used to obtain scroll values. They are similar in that they both retrieve the Y scroll value. However, it's important to note that `scrollY` does not work in Internet Explorer.

According to MDN (Mozilla Developer Network), you can use either property if you are not concerned about supporting legacy environments.

In essence, if you do not need to support older browsers, using scrollY is advisable. On the other hand, if your project requires compatibility with older browsers, then `pageYOffset` should be your choice.

In my practice, I often employ a conditional statement to utilize both:

```
window.scrollY || window.pageYOffSet

// OR

window.pageYOffSet || document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

This approach ensures compatibility across a wide range of browsers, maintaining functionality in both modern and older environments.

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollY instead.

There is slightly better support for pageYOffset than for scrollY in older browsers, but if you're not concerned about browsers more than a handful of years old, you can use either one.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset